# load table after insert ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

Please help me,
I have many problem.
I use bootstrap modal to add, insert data. I want to after insert load table without page. Thanks very much.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var $path     = 'http://localhost/Final/admin/giang_vien/';

$(document).ready(function() { 
 
 // submit form using $.ajax() method
 
 $('#insert_form').submit(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
  
  $.ajax({
   url: $path+'function/check.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: $(this).serialize() // it will serialize the form data
  })
  .done(function(data){
   $('#modalgv').modal('hide');
   $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
   $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  })
  .fail(function(){
   alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...'); 
  });
 });
 
});
```

Comment: Create the view in check.php file and echo out the view as html, in ajax call success append the response in your div - @Orange

Answer (score 0):

In done method you can fetch the data to load the table

```
$.ajax({
    url: $path+'function/check.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize() // it will serialize the form data
})
.done(function(data){
    $('#modalgv').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

    // fetch data to load the table
    // populate the table with the data
})
.fail(function(){
    alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
});
```